# File downloading from URL via GET method from VBA

Tags: vba, rest, curl, https

I have created a report via Amazon API. API returns url. Here is an instruction how to get the file

[image]

I tried the following code

```
Sub t()

TargetURL = "https://offline-report-storage-eu-west-1-prod.......d"
'Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
'Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HTTPReq.Option(4) = 13056 '
HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
HTTPReq.send 

End Sub
```

Look like the request is ok - State=200

[image]

But the file was not loaded.

When I copied the link to a browser I got the file. So, the link was correct.

How can I load the file without referring/opening the browser?

Comment: You are missing to save the data to a file (in Responsebody, ResponseStream, ResonseText the data is present)

Comment: @Shrotter, the thing is that It should be downloaded as *.gzip file from the link. There is an array of numeric values in the body, but it should be also some text and date values... Anyway, I can't decode the response and the approach is to get the file to be downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there,  just add a few more lines of code. I would use the ADODB.Stream to save the response a file:

```
   ' Is reqeust successful?
    If HTTPReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set FileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        FileStream.Open
        FileStream.Type = 1 ' Binary stream
        FileStream.Write HTTPReq.responseBody
        FileStream.Position = 0
        FileStream.SaveToFile LocalFileName, 2 ' Overwrite file exists
        FileStream.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & HTTPReq.Status & " " & HTTPReq.statusText
    End If
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

It should be a direct download, so try the much simpler method using the API call `URLDownloadToFile` as shown in my function:

```vb
' Download a file or a page with public access from the web.
' Returns 0 if success, error code if not.
'
' If parameter NoOverwrite is True, no download will be attempted
' if an existing local file exists, thus this will not be overwritten.
'
' Examples:
'
' Download a file:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/ProfileImages/%7Ba82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23%7D.jpg"
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProjectProfile.jpg"
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName)
'
' Download a page:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur?display=Print"
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProject1022704.html"
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName)
'
' Error codes:
' -2146697210   "file not found".
' -2146697211   "domain not found".
' -1            "local file could not be created."
'
' 2004-12-17. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' 2017-05-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added check for local file.
' 2017-06-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added option to no overwrite the local file.
'
Public Function DownloadFile( _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    ByVal LocalFileName As String, _
    Optional ByVal NoOverwrite As Boolean) _
    As Long
    
    Const BindFDefault  As Long = 0
    Const ErrorNone     As Long = 0
    Const ErrorNotFound As Long = -1

    Dim Result  As Long

    If NoOverwrite = True Then
        ' Page or file should not be overwritten.
        ' Check that the local file exists.
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            ' File exists. Don't proceed.
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
      
    ' Download file or page.
    ' Return success or error code.
    Result = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url & vbNullChar, LocalFileName & vbNullChar, BindFDefault, 0)
    
    If Result = ErrorNone Then
        ' Page or file was retrieved.
        ' Check that the local file exists.
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) = "" Then
            Result = ErrorNotFound
        End If
    End If
    
    DownloadFile = Result
  
End Function
```

taken from my repository at **GitHub**: [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl).

Comment: It works great! Thank you very much. And thank you for a link to your GitHub.  By the way what does `'Attribute VB_Name = "Internet"` means ?

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered, if you feel so. The code line is for _Microsoft Access_ itself only - when you ask it to _import_ a complete module, a _.bas_ file.